# Add widgets displaying "Hello World" to a defined webpage with a browser extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, widget

I'd like to have a widget display "Hello World !" with a browser extension when a user is on the webpage www.example.com .

Is this possible ?

Bruno

Comment: Can you be more specific please? Is it from a client or a server point of view?

Comment: @Jason From a client point of view (using Javascript).

Comment: Define "widget". I can think of several interpretations that would have completely different answers.

Comment: @David Dorward I want the page www.example to be displayed as usual and in the upper right corner of the page a box with "Hello World !" inside.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for information on how to create a bookmarklet (where you have to press a button to make Hello World appear) or a browser extension (which will affect the web page without direct user interaction once it's installed and configured).

Comment: @Bruno — Knowing what you want it to look like doesn't tell us much about what it is. do you plan to add JS to the site? run a browser extension (which browser)? run a separate application on the client? something else?

Comment: @David Dorward I'd like to use a browser extension.

Comment: @JamesEggers I'd prefer a browser extension.

Comment: For which browser? For that matter, have you looked at the documentation provided by the browser vendor and had a go at implementing this?

Comment: @David Dorward For Chrome, Firefox and IE (start with Chrome). I don't even know how to start. I'm only wondering if it's possible and if some tutorials speak (even lightly) about this.

Comment: That will be three completely separate extensions. I think both Chrome and Firefox will allow you to write them in JS. You might have to use a .NET language for IE. Pick one to start with, and read the docs for writing extensions from the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a CMS-like approach. A user 'logs in' and the database/cookie detects who's logged in. Once the user's 'workspace' information is loaded, it then draws the widget of the user's choice on the browser.

Am I explaining that correctly? If so, this sounds more database-centric, user-driven.

Yes, it is possible.

Comment: I'd prefer to ask only the user to have an extension rather than having a database or a cookie system but if you know something with cookies I'm all ears :-) !

Comment: What is the extension/widget called, if I may ask?

Comment: The extension is for Chrome (to start) and I'd like a widget able to display text.

Comment: What is the name of the widget for Chrome? I think you could just embed the extension and have it fire automatically.